AES256GCM streaming question
The question here is regarding big files with AES256GCM and streaming them. I want to read only a part of a file using something similar as a file stream. So for example I want to be able to read some bytes from chunk 64 (@ 64MB offset for example) without having to decrypt the entire file or run over the entire file to verify the tag (as the file might be very long). Decrypting the single chunk and loading it into the temporary buffer is fine though. As long as I don't have to read the entire file. From top of my head I could do the following:
I could do so by having a chunk per 1MB which has an auth tag. These auth tags could be stored after the header of the file and would be 16 bytes * ceil(fileSize / chunkSize) (basically just an array of 16 byte stride), after which another tag follows as auth for those tags (to ensure the tags themselves are valid first). The tags of all chunks would be in memory, so when you load a chunk you could verify that tag before writing it into the intermediate buffer. And the tag has already been verified before starting any decryption (by the tag of tags). As extra security, I could pick 3 random (or the first 3) chunks to verify that their tags match first.
If the stream detects a mismatching tag it could return an error to let the caller know that it should stop doing whatever it's doing since the data is either corrupt or invalid.
Is this considered good practice or is something like AES PMAC SIV better for this and if so what advantages does it have?
Thanks

Could you maybe formalize the description? As it is it is impossible - at least for me - what you are trying to do. You want to stream a file that has been encrypted in place? You are adding the list of authentication tags of each chunk at the end, but during streaming you verify them first? In your description you decrypt first, but at streaming time you decrypt again?

I've closed this question for now until the protocol is better described. Please comment below or flag once you've clarified the question using an [edit].

@MaartenBodewes I want to read only a part of a file using something similar as a file stream. So for example I want to be able to read some bytes from chunk 64 (@ 64MB in for example) without having to decrypt the entire file or run over the entire file to verify the tag (as the file might be very long). Decrypting the single chunk and loading it into the temporary buffer is fine though. As long as I don't have to read the entire file. The auth tags would be after the header of the file and would be 16 bytes * ceil(fileSize / chunkSize), after which another tag follows as auth for those tags.

The tags of all chunks would be in memory, so when you load a chunk you could verify that tag before writing it into the intermediate buffer. And the tag has already been verified before starting any decryption (by the tag of tags).

Great, that makes it much more clear. However, please integrate this into the question as requested so I can reopen it! Comments should not be used for information that is vital to understanding the question.

@MaartenBodewes Updated the question, please let me know if it's clearer now.

Yup, opened it up again!
